# Cordova copy/paste menu is grey

Tags: android, cordova, webview

In a cordova app when selecting text and bringing up the copy/paste menu on marshmallow it's background color is not the default white but instead grey. How do you change it back to the default?

Heres a picture for clarity

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have a perfect solution for you.

You could use [*cordova-custom-config*-Plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config).
After installing it:

*cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config*

or

*phonegap plugin add cordova-custom-config*

You can easyly modify an android theme just by modifing your config.xml file. My cordova-testapp uses Holo-Light theme for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.testapp955851" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>testapp</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
    ....
    ....
  <preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:theme" value="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />

</widget>
```

To see the changings you could test these themes for instance: 
@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault, @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light or @android:style/Theme.Holo.

---

When you want to make your own theme, just use this [generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100).(it is deprecated but nevertheless good enough for an example).

After generating your own theme, downloading and unzipping it, you have to **put all drawable-files** **into** your android project-folder(**platforms/android/res**). After these style-files are in your project the last thing you have to do is to **copy** your theme-defintions **from** your downloaded/unzipped style_example.xml(**res/values/style_example.xml**) **into** your project style-file called strings.xml(**platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml**).

After doing this my strings.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">testapp</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
    <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>

    <!-- ONYL PUT style-tags INTO strings.xml -->
    <style name="Theme.YourOwnTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
    </style>
.....
.....
</resources>
```

Furthermore I've renamed this theme Theme.YourOwnTheme to show that you are really using a modified theme. Accordingly I changed the theme-name in config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:theme" value="@style/Theme.YourOwnTheme" />
```

Finish!

Although it has been testet on a samsung galaxy S4(Lollipop, version: 5.0.1) it should work on marshmallow  as well.

Another helpful [link](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/82/how-to-enable-material-native-theme-on-android-within-a-cordova-application).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked. I'm surprised that this isn't exposed by default in cordova and must be extended with a plugin. It seems so basic.

Comment: I know what you mean. The reason might be that the platforms(android, ios) differ too much. I can not come up with another reason. As you said, it seems basic.