# Status bar not changing during the splash screen loading Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, statusbar

I am using the [ionic plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git).

And it works fine but when the app loads it doesn't implement the color chosen during the splash screen.

**app.js**

```
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#11c1f3");
    } else {
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  }
```

I already have the splash screen plugin installed.

Comment: what is your device api level

Comment: from the config, i can see this:   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/> adn the phone android versoin is 5.0.2

Comment: this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360733/cordova-copy-paste-menu-is-grey/39366993#39366993) might help you. there is a plugin, you can style native ui-components.